# How to remove the gloss effect from app icon in ipad 5.1, 6.0, .7.0 together?

Tags: ios, ipad

I read alot about setting off the gloss effect from the app icon,
for now I can get the gloss effect removed from ios6,7 but not for ios5.1 (ipad)

In the info.plist,
What I need to enter in Icon Files(iOS 5), **in case** I also have the
CFBundleIcons~ipad for ios6,ios7 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "remove the gloss effect from ipad" - displace it from the way of the light beam...

Answer (score 3):

for xcode5 select select pre rendered checkbox for the right asset

[image]

Comment: I'm not using asset categlog. it's under App Icons (general tap)

Answer (score 2):

To disable just add `UIPrerenderedIcon` to `YES` under `CFBundleIcons` in info.Plist. For reference i have attached image below.

[image: Plist]

Answer (score 0):

Near  a box where an icon added there is a tickbox "Prerendered". Did you tick it?

Comment: where ? I'm not using asset categlog.
I can see list of app icons,but I dont see "Prerendered" tickbox.

Comment: the xcode version doesn't really have to do with the rendered icons. Xcode is mainly just an IDE. It would be related to the device it is deployed on and for ios6 you still need / can set this

Comment: I don't even this is right since question explicity states iOS 5-7

Comment: If you're not using xcassets, the "Prerendered" tick box doesn't exist in Xcode 5.